# Get the value from the file & add the values in an array...But getting values multiple times

Tags: arrays, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -a line; do

for raw_value in $line; do

raw_value_1=`echo $line | sed "s/,/ /g" | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}'`
raw_value_2=`echo $line | sed "s/,/ /g" | head -n1 | awk '{print $2;}'`
raw_value_3=`echo $line | sed "s/,/ /g" | head -n1 | awk '{print $3;}'`
REPO=`echo $raw_value_1`
BRANCH=`echo $raw_value_2`
TAG=`echo $raw_value_3`

echo $REPO
echo $BRANCH
echo $TAG

done

arrVar=("$REPO" "$BRANCH" "$TAG")

for value in "${arrVar[@]}"
do

cmd="echo ${arrVar[@]}"
           cmd_out=$($cmd)
           status=$?

           if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]
           then
echo "First Repo is ${arrVar[0]}; Branch is ${arrVar[1]}"
     echo ${arrVar[2]}
fi
done
done < /var/lib/jenkins/Jack/test
```

My File content -

Jack,master,1.0.1
Tom,master,1.0.2

Desired output -

Repo is Jack; Branch is master
Tag is 1.0.1

Repo is Tom; Branch is master
1.0.2

Current output -

Jack
master
1.0.1
Repo is Jack; Branch is master
1.0.1
Repo is Jack; Branch is master
1.0.1
Repo is Jack; Branch is master
1.0.1
Tom
master
1.0.2
Repo is Tom; Branch is master
1.0.2
Repo is Tom; Branch is master
1.0.2
Repo is Tom; Branch is master
1.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your purpose is, but given this input

```sh
cat file.txt
```

```
Jack,master,1.0.1
Tom,master,1.0.2
```

here's how to parse the data with three different action scenarios:

```sh
while IFS=, read -r repo branch tag; do
  
  # Printing your "desired output"
  printf 'Repo is %s; Branch is %s\nTag is %s\n\n' \
    "$repo" "$branch" "$tag"
  
  # Populating an array (three more elements per input row)
  arrVar+=("$repo" "$branch" "$tag")
  
  # the git command from your answer post
  git clone -b "${branch}" "ssh://git@test.com:8080/test_dir/${repo}.git"
  git tag "${tag}"

done < file.txt
```

The printing scenario would output

```
Repo is Jack; Branch is master
Tag is 1.0.1

Repo is Tom; Branch is master
Tag is 1.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help @pmf. But I've to use this arrVar to clone all Repo names (Jack, Tom & so on...). 
Clone all the Repos one by one which is listed in the file.txt file. 
I tried this -

`code`
```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r repo branch tag; do
  printf 'Repo is %s; Branch is %s\nTag is %s\n\n' \
    "$repo" "$branch" "$tag"
arrVar+=("$repo" "$branch" "$tag")
for value in "${arrVar[@]}"
do
git clone -b "${arrVar[@]}" ssh://git@test.com:8080/test_dir/"${arrVar[0]}".git
git tag ${arrVar[3]}
done
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Could u plz suggest?? I've added my question as an answer...

Comment: @user8051342 I'm no expert in git. Judging merely on the looks of your code, you probably shouldn't iterate over the array, in fact there seems to be no need for an array at all. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. It's working as expected.... –

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick help @pmf. But I've to use this arrVar to clone all Repo names (Jack, Tom & so on...).
Clone all the Repos one by one which is listed in the file.txt file.
I tried this But not working -

`code`

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r repo branch tag; do
  printf 'Repo is %s; Branch is %s\nTag is %s\n\n' \
    "$repo" "$branch" "$tag"
arrVar+=("$repo" "$branch" "$tag")
for value in "${arrVar[@]}"
do
git clone -b "${arrVar[@]}" ssh://git@test.com:8080/test_dir/"${arrVar[0]}".git
git tag ${arrVar[3]}
done
done < file.txt
```

Comment: I'm no expert in git. Judging merely on the looks of your code, you probably shouldn't iterate over the array, in fact there seems to be no need for an array at all. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. It's working as expected....